# C - Comparing a string in a 2D Array against another string

Tags: c, arrays, string

So, I have a 2D array for storing client ids in my program. I have to write a routine where I iterate through each string in this array and compare it against another string. I am using strcmp() for this. Following is the code.

```
char client_ids[100][100];

int find_client_by_id(char* name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(&client_ids[i], name) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It does what it is supposed to do, and returns the index of the passed string if found in the array and -1 otherwise. The issue I am facing is that on compiling I get the following warning,

```
server.c: In function ‘find_client_by_id’:
server.c:30:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
if (strcmp(&client_ids[i], name) == 0)
          ^
In file included from server.c:5:0:
/usr/include/string.h:140:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[100]’
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to avoid this warning?

Comment: Because `client_ids` is already (decays into) a pointer, you don't need to pass the address of (`&`). Switch to `if (strcmp(client_ids[i], name) == 0)`

Comment: `&client_ids[i]` takes the address of the array, but you wanted to pass the address of the first char in an array. Remove the address of operator and the resulting array is converted to the address of the first element.

Comment: @KeineLust Thank you very much! Can't believe I missed this.

Comment: Neither can I... which book are you reading?